# React and Django deployment blank page and 404 errors on static files with cpanel

Tags: python, reactjs, django, deployment, cpanel

I wanted to deploy my django and react application on my domain name via my host

I have setup my python because when we go to the url dimitridenis.com/admin we arrive at my django admin portal, I implemented React and did the npm install then the build in my cpanel terminal, however I found myself with a white screen and 404 errors on static files, I tried several times to change my build, the paths in my settings.py file but I still don't understand

[White screen with errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXSGD.png)

If you have any ideas to give me, I'm interested